# UITableview Cell animation play only once

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I want to animate `UITableViewCell` only once when it displays the first time.

my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.alpha = 0
    let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 200, 0)
    cell.layer.transform = transform

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        cell.alpha = 1
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    })
}
```

Animation works great, but the problem is, that animation also gets performed when the user scrolls up direction because of the cell is reused. and that doesn't look good.

I want to show animation **once** for each cell, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Create one function for entire tableview and called after view did load

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to record the cell whose animation is done for that you can maintain an array...

Create a property for that.

```
var arrIndexPath = [IndexPath]()
```

And then do the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     
if arrIndexPath.contains(indexPath) == false {
        cell.alpha = 0
        let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 200, 0)
        cell.layer.transform = transform
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.alpha = 1
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        })
        
        arrIndexPath.append(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add an array to your ViewController with for example bool flag for each cell.

```
var cellAnimationsFlags = Array(repeatElement(false, count: yourDataSourceArray.count))
```

Then check it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if self.cellAnimationsFlags[indexPath.row] {
        return
    }
    cell.alpha = 0
    let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 200, 0)
    cell.layer.transform = transform
    self.cellAnimationsFlags[indexPath.row] = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        cell.alpha = 1
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    })
}
```